# How can the terminal follow the resizing of my editor?

Tags: c, view, resize, width

I'm writing a simple program in C on Visual Studio Code for a project, and the professor asked that after compiling and running the project (it prints some ascii characters) everything that has been printed should follow the "resizing" of the Visual Studio Code page:

eg if I exit Full Screen mode with Visual Studio and start shrinking the page, the text should be able to follow its movement and change accordingly, instead of just being "covered" by the page and disappearing.

Pics for reference:
[image: What it is in Full Screen]
VS
[image: What it is when resizing]

I haven't found anything relevant online and I really haven't tried that much since I'm not an expert

Comment: It is a pity they teach you such irrelevant and platform dependent things, tell them to teach you something more productive.

Comment: This is very hard to do in C and will be very system dependent. It seems strange that a professor would ask for this. You likely need to catch the SIGWINCH signal, then use the ncurses library to get the width of the screen, then re-output your results taking the width into account. Can you say what operating system you are running on?